# Get URL paramater after page load

Tags: php, jquery

I use jquery to load a script.php file after loading my index.php page and I want to be able to retrieve the parameter of my URL in my script.php file but it doesn't work because the page is already loaded and it tells me

```
Undefined array key "query"
```

index.php :

```
 <div id="loader">
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('#loader').load('scripts.php');
    })
```

scripts.php :

```
    $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parts = parse_url($current_url);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    $parameter = $query['q'];
```

URL example :
https://example.com/search?q=test

Is there any way to get my parameter back after loading the page ?

thank you in advance

Comment: That query string value was passed to `index.php`, not to `scripts.php`.  Do they both need it?  Can you just add the value to the URL for `scripts.php`?  I don't really see what the intended functionality or end result is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arbitrary query string parameters to `scripts.php`, just like you would any other URL:

```
...load('scripts.php?q=' + variable)
```

However there is no way for `scripts.php` to know what parameters were involved in the request to `index.php`.

You'd have to forward anything you're interested in making `scripts.php` aware of.

However, it's not really clear why you would do this. You typically shouldn't be assembling multiple related PHP pages on the frontend, over several HTTP requests. Rather, your PHP pages should just include the necessary related components, and serve up a complete document in a single request.

Instead of having `index.php` serve up some JavaScript that makes another round-trip request for `scripts.php`, forwarding details about the original request, why not just have `index.php` `require( "scripts.php");`, so that it is *part* of the original request?

Comment: Because my scripts.php takes a little time to load and I want users to see the page first and then load scripts.php instead of making the request and loading on the previous page while waiting for scripts.php to load

Comment: It works perfectly, but without a space :
`search?q=title`
but it doesn't work with an space : 
`/search?q=title%20title2`
I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request to `scripts.php` is a **different** HTTP request to the one make to the URL that returns the HTML document. It has a different URL.

If you want to copy the query string from the latter then you need to do so explicitly.

```
const q = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
const url = new URL("search.php", location);
[...q.entries()].forEach(
    ([key, value]) => url.searchParams.append(key, value)
);
$('#loader').load(url.toString());
```